# upload image to Facebook with FBSDKShareButton

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I read the `FacebookSDK`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/send-button, and I only see the imageURL to upload to Facebook.

```
NSURL *contentURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:
  @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"];

NSURL *imageURL = 
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg"];

_sendButton.shareContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]
  initWithContentURL: contentURL
  contentTitle: @"My Share Title"
  contentDescription: @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
  imageURL: imageURL
  peopleIDs: nil
  placeID: nil
  ref: nil
];
```

I've tried something with `shareButton`:

```
let shareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        shareButton.center = view.center
        let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentTitle = caption
        content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg")
        shareButton.shareContent = content
        view.addSubview(shareButton)
```

I can upload this to my timeline easily.

But I only want to send my image which I get from PhotoLibrary to upload to Facebook. Is is possible because I when I try `content.image` (there are no hint with this this)

Comment: Facebook or wikipedia? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: Save it to disk before sharing

Comment: @LeoDabus Then I have to get this URL from Disk and upload to my Timeline?

Comment: Yes just save it to a temporary file

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. Tomorrow I will try, it's time to go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using FBSDKShareLinkContent, which only allows you to share links (and img urls). If you want to share a photo to Facebook, you'll need to use the FBSDKSharePhotoContent or FBSDKShareMediaContent classes where you can add an array of UIImage objects.

See the Catalog sample app that ships with the SDK to see how to use this in practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, is it possible to assign my text without having to write the title on it by hand?

Comment: Do you mean the user message? If so, then no, you can't specify the user message. You can, however, set a hashtag in the share content.